# undefined method `charities_path' for #<#<Class:0x000000035ab3f8>:0x0000000344f220>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm facing this error for quite some time now, I've tried a lot of solutions but none is working. Making my scenario clear :
1) I'm not using scaffold command & creating the whole thing manually
2) The error is generated on trying to create a new Charity

**ERROR:**

```
Showing /home/hitesh/Rails/ReachOut/app/views/charity/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `charities_path' for #<#<Class:0x000000035ab3f8>:0x0000000344f220>

Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= form_for(@charity) do |f| %>
2:   <% if @charity.errors.any? %>
3:     <div id="error_explanation">
4:       <h2><%= pluralize(@charity.errors.count, "error") %> THis is where i screwed prohibited this charity from being saved:</h2>
```

**MY _form.html.erb LOOKS LIKE THIS :**

```
  <%= form_for(@charity) do |f| %>
    <% if @charity.errors.any? %>
       <div id="error_explanation">
         <h2><%= pluralize(@charity.errors.count, "error") %> THis is where i screwed prohibited this charity from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @charity.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
```

**MY routes.rb contains the entry for a charity**

```
ReachOut::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :charity

  # The priority is based upon order of creation:
  # first created -> highest priority.
```

**My CharityController :**

```
class CharityController < ApplicationController

        # GET /charity/new
        # GET /charity/new.json
        def new
                @charity = Charity.new

                respond_to do |format|
                        format.html #new.html.erb
                        format.json { render json: @charity}
                end
        end
```

**and My charity.rb (MODEL) :** does contain a charity class

...

Guys I;ve tried a lot of things (changing @ => :) but still m not able to remove this error ... Hope anyone of you can help me in it... I searched for charities_path in my whole system and could find nothing :) :(.

Answer (score 3):

you need `resources :charities` in routes.rb

And controller must be named as CharitiesController

Or you must manually set path helper method, but in this case you can face another problems, better follow rails naming rules

Comment: Can you guide me how to set path helper method ... I'm quite new to it.

Comment: It's better rename controller, if you are quite new and don't understand possible problems you face with.